# Getting Razor page name for conditional loading of script in layout page

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

I need to conditionally load a script in a the layout page of a Razor pages application (the script needs to be loaded after other scripts have loaded but assumes the existence of elements only on one page).

I want to use something like

```
@{
   if (Page.Name == "page_name") {

      <script src="~/js/myscript.js"></script>
   }
}
```

but can find no method for getting the page name.

Can anyone please recommend a way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you pass the script to a section from the page where it is intended to be used?

Comment: Because it needs to be loaded after the site.js script (uses methods from it), which is loaded by the layout page. Both need to be loaded after the body loads as they use HTML elements.

Comment: BTW, I have gotten around the problem by making the JavaScript code conditional on the page URL by interrogating window.location.href - but I did want to know how to do this in the Razor pages themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to create a new section in the layout, below the existing scripts and then target that from the page that utilises the script:

Layout:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
@RenderSection("ExtraScripts", false)
```

Then in the page that needs to use the script:

```
@section ExtraScripts{
    <script src="~/js/myscripts.js"></script>
}
```

Sections: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/layout#sections

If you want the contents of myscripts to load after the body has loaded, put it in a jQuery ready function, or a DomContentLoaded event handler.

DomContentLoaded : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event